# Can i load a image from FTP to my image view in my iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ftp, uiimageview

I have some images in FTP , and i need to display those images in a image view in my iphone app, is it possible to load the image with out downloading it, just by loading the FTP Image URL to the image view?

Answer (score 1):

Check out Apple's [simple FTP example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009243).

Once you have access to the FTP server:

```
NSURL *theUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"ftp://userid:password@your.server/image.png"];
UIImage *newImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
UIImageView *newImageView = [UIImageView imageViewWithImage:newImage];
```

Keep in mind that this process takes time so do the work on a background thread to ensure app responsiveness.

Comment: `imageWithContentsOfUrl` Doesn't exist. Maybe you mean something like :  `UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];`?

Comment: Sure do, thanks for the remark

Comment: Wouldn't it come in handy if there were such a method, though? :)

Comment: You can always just make one :)

Comment: I did, I got so accustomed to using it that I forgot it's a category I made

Answer (score 1):

There is a pretty cool library called [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). It downloads the image asynchronously, so your app stays responsive. It adds a category to UIImageView so you just have to pass the url to the ImageView and everything will be done automatically for you. It also works with `ftp://` urls.

Something like this should work:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,50.0f,50.0f)];

[imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"ftp://example.com/path/image.jpeg"]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

You can also specify a placeholder that is shown as long the image isn't downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use just FTP URL for the image to load.

Comment: Thanx for ur reply but we need to set Credentials for that FTP know,,can u pls post some code to do so

Comment: Set Public read permission for the image file so that program can access the image without credentials. Or please try ftp://username:password@hostname/testimage.png